# Is it possible for a tiefling to be a druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, tiefling

I'm a newbie and I'm creating a character for the first time. Is possible for a tiefling to be a druid? I noticed that druids hate unnatural things and monsters; if someone takes a tiefling as a monster, would that mean this combination is against the rules?

Answer (score 31):

#### The druid class contains no racial constraints, and the tiefling race contains no class constraints.

There is no conflict here. There is nothing in the rules that would prevent a tiefling from being a druid.

The only class with a racial restriction is the Path of the Battlerager barbarian (*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*):

> ##### Restriction: Dwarves Only
>
> Only dwarves can follow the Path of the Battlerager. The battlerager fills a particular niche in dwarven society and culture.
>
> Your DM can lift this restriction to better suit the campaign. The restriction exists for the Forgotten Realms. It might not apply to your DM’s setting or your DM’s version of the Realms.

So *if* a particular class has a racial restriction, this is what it would look like. But even this rule says the DM may allow it.

Comment: Interesting that Battlerager wasn't updated when Bladesinger was.

Comment: @GuidingOlive Bladesingers never had an explicit restriction like battleragers, though their lore description was updated to be more inclusive.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Bladesingers did have the "Restriction: Elves Only" tag in SCAG. At least I see it in my 2015 printing of the book.

Comment: @RallozarX Thank god, I don't own SCAG so I wasn't prepared to defend that statement but I remembered them having a restriction tied to them.

Comment: @RallozarX Yep, double checked mine too l, you are correct. I just have replaced it with the errata in my brain.

Answer (score 11):

#### In short, yes

As of dnd-5e, race/class restrictions are largely eliminated (with the only notable exception very exceptional subclasses). So it's entirely possible for a Tiefling to become a druid.

Narratively, this could occur in multiple ways such as a child of druids and/or elves suddenly develops the traits of a Tiefling (a mention to Fig Faeth of Dimension 20's Fantasy High for this idea). Another option might be a being under the effect of the spell Reincarnation.

And as Thomas says in their answer, ultimately it's also DM's discretion. On the other hand, they very well could put such a restriction in that doesn't exist in the rules but in my experience you'd be hard pressed to find a DM like that.

Comment: Thomas's answer is saying a DM can *waive* racial restrictions that do exist in written rules, like allowing a non-dwarf Battlerager.  (Or a non-Elf Bladesinger, before errata updated that subclass to make it official that non-elves could be bladesingers.)  A DM *could* disallow certain race/class combos that the books do allow. But most likely they just want to maintain consistency of their campaign setting, and as you say most would be happy with a narrative justification for anything unusual.

Answer (score -2):

There is no rule set in stone that you can’t have a PC tiefling who is a druid.  I would ask your DM, in the situation that it may be odd for your campaign and backstory.

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything new to the discussion and you don't back it up either. It would be much better to go in detail about "he situation that it may be odd for your campaign and backstory." why that might be a worry and so on.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE.  The [tour], [help], [ask] and [answer] provide guidance on how to get the best results from an SE formatted site, which isn't a forum and isn't a reddit.  Supported answers are the preference, and if you can support your valid point - check with your DM is good advice for a newbie, they may not realize that this is important to do - with either experience or a reference to the Players Handbook on character creation, the answer would be improved.